# Передача ГЕТ параметра в JS

Tags: javascript

скажите пожалуйста как передать гет параметр в changeLang(ru); например ?lang=en

```
function changeLang(lan) {
  lengthObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lan).length;
  for (let i = 0; i <= lengthObj - 1; i++) {
    objKey = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lan)[i];
    document.getElementById(objKey).innerText = func(objKey);
  }

  function func(a) {
    for (key in lan) {
      if (key == a) {
        return (lan[key]);
      }
    }
  }
}

changeLang(ru)
```

Answer (score 0):

Банально:

```
location.search
```

А если взять значение по имени, то вот так:

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
let lang = searchParams.get("lang");
```

Comment: a как добавить в ```changeLang()```?

Comment: Добавить так, как я написал

Comment: changeLang() удалить?

Comment: Зачем удалять? Вы же хотели передавать туда параметр.

Comment: Не сработало из-за того что большая часть написана на php и перевод выполняется через редерект записью в  куки, как може взять параметр из куки?
Сделал так но не работате
`let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
let LANGUAGE = searchParams.cookie("LANGUAGE");
changeLang();`

Comment: Если возник другой вопрос - задайте новый вопрос............и мне не ясно тут одно: вы пишите `как передать гет параметр в changeLang` и при этом упорно вызываете `changeLang` без передачи параметра. В чём прикол?

Comment: Вы правы вопрос был задан про гет параметр, но потом я увидел что его не возможно передать из-за редиректа. И поэтому задал вопрос про куки. Что касается changeLang я не знаю js и по этой причине не понимаю что делаю. Я вам очень благодарен что оказываете помощ.

Comment: *"его не возможно передать из-за редиректа."* --- то есть в URL нет строки вида `?lang=en` ?

Comment: как я уже писал перевод на сайте написать на php и только к части кода применяется перевод на js, для перевода есть ссылка href="/rus/" при переходе по ней идет отправка в файл где записываются куки с названием файла перевода и моментыльный редирект обратно. По этой причине если я добавляю в ссылку /rus/?lang=ru идет редирект, а по возвращению ссылка уже пуста